# detect how many characters cant print in a line

Tags: c#

How can I detect how many characters I can print in a line, considering that I have a certain font, I show you my code:

```
var pr = new PrintDocument();
pr.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
pr.PrintPage += (sender, args) => pr__PrintPage(pr, args);
pr.Print();

private static void pr__PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var font = new Font("Lucida Console", 10);
    var text = new string('A', number_or_characters);
    e.Graphics.DrawString($"{text}", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);

    // number_or_characters = should be calculated based on the source
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Graphics.MeasureString`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: @pedroPG All things being equal, 72 points is one inch. Unless you're using a fixed-width font, you'll need to measure the actual string in question to determine if it'll fit.

Comment: @3Dave the unit in fonts is Point, as I know which is the unit of PrintDocument ¿?

Comment: The API link that @DmitryBychenko shared details all of this.

Comment: I see, and how do I get the width available for printing?

Comment: Read the `PrintPageEventArgs` properties. You have `e.MarginBounds` and `e.PageBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You are seeking an answer that doesn't exist as the font you are using is proportional.  Just because two strings have the same number of characters does not mean they have the same width.  You must measure the string you wish to draw.